# Bootstrap 3  в Internet Explorer 8 отображается как для мобильных

Tags: bootstrap

Здравствуйте, может подскажите в решении проблемы. 
При использовании bootstrap 3 - Internet Explorer 8 отображает сайт как мобильную версию, как можно решить проблему (почему-то использование respond не помогло, или что-то не так делаю?)

```
 <![endif]
     [if lt IE 8]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы пишете про IE 8, а [условие задано](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/internet-explorer/uslovnye-kommentarii) для IE 7 и ниже. Попробуйте `lt` заменить на `lte`